# javascript Image Editing

Tags: javascript

I want a simple image editor functionality for my site. My requirement is like that an image is being displayed and user can draw squares and shapes on image and save the co-ordinates so that when the image is reloaded the area are highlighted. So we have to provide a simple toolbox to user so that he can do the image editing on runtime.

There are few scripts available for the purpose but none seems to be close to my requirement. Can you people recommend a good script for that that is cross browser too?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Raphel js
http://raphaeljs.com
You can check this also
http://jsvectoreditor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html